# Change country cookie in selenium webdriver using mocha

Tags: selenium-webdriver, set, mocha.js, setcookie

I want to check certain elements on a website with different country cookie.
I tried using `addCookie()` but it is not working for me.  Below is the code.Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
 var assert = require('assert'),
 test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
 webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
 var url = process.env.URL;
 var driver;
 function createDriver() {
 var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
    .build();
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15000);
return driver;
} 
 test.describe('Checking Ringo Home Page', function() {
 this.timeout(20000);
 test.before(function(){
 driver = createDriver();
});
test.after(function(){
driver.quit();
});
test.it('Wifi Element', function() {   
driver.get(url).then(function(){
driver.manage().addCookie("src_country", "GB", "http://www.ringo.co");
driver.navigate().refresh().then(function(){
driver.sleep(1000);   
driver.manage().window().maximize().then(function(){
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[@id='features-option']/div[2]/div[1]/div/span")).then(function(element){
  console.log("Wifi Present")
    element.isDisplayed().then(function(value){
      if(value){
     console.log("Wifi Visible");
    }else{
      assert.fail("Wifi Missing");
  }});});});});});})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 var assert = require('assert'),
 test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
 webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
 var url = process.env.URL;
 var driver;

 function createDriver() {
 var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
    .build();

driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15000);
return driver;
 }
test.describe('Checking Ringo Home Page', function() {
this.timeout(50000);
test.before(function() {
driver = createDriver();
});
test.after(function() {
driver.quit();
});
test.it('Wifi Element', function() {
driver.get(url).then(function() {
driver.sleep(1000);
driver.manage().addCookie("src_country", "GB");
driver.manage().getCookie('src_country').then(function(cookie) {
    console.log(cookie.value);
});
driver.navigate().refresh().then(function() {
    driver.sleep(1000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize().then(function() {
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[@id='features-     option']/div[2]/div[1]/div/span")).then(function(element) {
            console.log("Wifi Present")
            driver.executeScript("scroll(0,700)");
    driver.sleep(500)
            element.isDisplayed().then(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    console.log("Wifi Visible");
                } else {
                    assert.fail("Wifi Missing");
                }
            });
        });
    });
  });
 });

 });

 })
```

Cheers :)